# numpy: mean over different subset of each row in matrix

Tags: python, numpy, subset

Given the following matrix

```
In [1]: a
Out[1]: 
array([[106.74    , 108.072   , 108.72    , 109.584   , 108.468   ],
       [114.012   , 114.156   , 107.928   , 113.904   , 112.968   ],
       [114.396225, 115.21124 , 116.01796 , 115.0901  , 113.01843 ]],
      dtype=float32)
```

I can compute the mean of each subset of row like this,

```
In [2]: np.mean(a[:,1:3],axis=1)
Out[2]: array([108.395996, 111.042   , 115.6146  ], dtype=float32)
```

But what I am trying to do now, is the following,

given a set of indices `i = [3,4,3]`

I want to have the means of

```
a[0,1:3]

a[1,1:4]

a[3,1:2]
```

respectively,

so, naturally my first attempt was,

```
In [2]: np.mean(a[:,1:i],axis=1)
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

which certainly does not work.

I also know about this,

```
In [3]: a[np.where(i)+(i,)]
Out[3]: array([108.468 , 113.904 , 115.0901], dtype=float32)
```

But I didn't manage to find out hwo to combine them....

Any ideas?

update after @luciole75w and @Friedrich answers,

I compare running time for both versions,

```
print(a.shape,ii.shape)
#
t = time.time()
mu1b=np.array([np.mean(a[j,0:i]) for j,i in enumerate(ii)])
print(time.time() - t)
# 
t = time.time()
col = np.arange(a.shape[1]).reshape(-1, 1)
istart = 0         # or variable, e.g. istart = [1, 1, 1]
istop = ii  # or fixed, e.g. istop = 3
tmask = (istart <= col) & (col < istop)
mu1 = np.nansum(a.T*tmask,axis=0)/tmask.sum(axis=0)
print(time.time() - t)
```

results in,

```
(740832, 30) (740832,)
7.258646249771118
0.5934605598449707
```

@luciole75w version based on @AndrasDeak suggestion is way more efficient.

Comment: Since the number of items in each row varies it won't be easy to do this with idiomatic numpy. Can you easily define a boolean mask? You could do `(arrr * mask).sum(1)/mask.sum(1)` or so.

Comment: You can use `sum` instead of `nansum` in the nominator. Or use also `np.isnan(a.T)` when creating `tmask`.

Comment: @Friedrich That doesn't work because if you have `nan`'s in `a` no matter they are `False` or `True` in the mask, in the multiplication `a.T*tmask` those values become `nan` and `sum` would return `nan` for that row.

Comment: Then, if you don't use `np.isnan`, your means are wrong. E.g. `tmask = [True,True, True]; a = np.array([1., 1., np.nan]); np.nansum(a*tmask)/np.sum(tmask)`. Returns 0.666, while you expect 1. Or you implicitly propagate `nan` as zero.

Comment: You are absolutely right!. I  didn't see it because in my particular matrix the `nan`s are always after the position `ii`

Comment: If the `NaN` values are always located outside the row slices, then you can simply get rid of them using `np.where` instead of the multiplication, which is actually cleaner and also a bit faster, so I'm going to update the answer. Another minor optimization could be to use `(istop - istart)` as denominator if you only use numpy arrays (or scalars) for bounds (and no `NaN` inside slices ofc).

Comment: @luciole75w I don't really see what you mean by removing the multiplication and replacing it by a `where`. wasn't the mask multiplication the solution in the first place?

Comment: Well the operations `a * mask` and `np.where(mask, a, 0)` give a very close result, both can be used here (please see my answer update) but the latter is not polluted by `NaN` values outside the slices/mask (and is also better overall, I should have preferred this option in the first place). Now if you cannot have `NaN` *inside* slices then that's all you need. Otherwise the mask has to include `~np.isnan(a.T)` as Friedrich pointed out.

Comment: great. It's indeed a good improvement for this particular case where I have `nan`s outside the mask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good idea from Andras, I'd also use the same approach. The mask could be built with something like :

```
istart = 1         # or variable, e.g. istart = [1, 2, 1]
istop = [3, 4, 3]  # or fixed, e.g. istop = 3

col = np.arange(a.shape[1]).reshape(-1, 1)

tmask = (istart <= col) & (col < istop)
#array([[False, False, False],
#       [ True,  True,  True],
#       [ True,  True,  True],
#       [False,  True, False],
#       [False, False, False]], dtype=bool)

np.where(tmask, a.T, 0).sum(axis=0) / tmask.sum(axis=0)
```

---

```
array([ 108.396 ,  111.996 ,  115.6146])
```

Note that the mask is transposed so that input bounds can be easily written using native python types (since they are applied along axis 0).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generator expression

```
a = np.array([[106.74    , 108.072   , 108.72    , 109.584   , 108.468   ],
              [114.012   , 114.156   , 107.928   , 113.904   , 112.968   ],
              [114.396225, 115.21124 , 116.01796 , 115.0901  , 113.01843 ]])

[np.mean(a[j,1:i]) for j,i in zip([0,1,2],[3,4,2])]
```

This returns: `[108.396, 111.996, 114.156]`.

Arrays are meant to work with rows and columns of same length. But with your end indices you intend rows of different length.

Comment: But isn't a for loop in this case quite inefficient?

Comment: It is a pythonic loop. And I think, your problem will not be a bottleneck or time critical.

Comment: It's good that you posted (+1) because I should have tried that one. It might be pythonic in the sense that is a one-liner, but the way it works is exactly as a regular for loop. I am updating my answer comparing runnig time of your version and the one from @luciole75w .